How can I edit typo3 header template to add tracking codes or GTM
I have been handled 3 websites. 2 of them are using typo3 and I have no experience on this CMS. Been trying to understand how can I edit template files but absolutely got no information valuable.
Marketing team sent tracking codes to add to header template on these 2 sites but it's been a week and I still couldn't find a solution on how to do this 15 seconds task.
Can you guide me step by step if it's possible. Thank you. Version is 11.5.10.

Downloaded all files from FTP and checked almost all of them for header template
Read documentation but it's very confusing and couldn't understand anything
Tried to contact with old agency who built the site but they're not working for the company anymore
Searched web for a solution, hit a rock wall.


TYPO3 is one of the most flexible content management systems on the market. This means that developers can implement solutions in various ways. It heavily depends on how the previous developers implemented and configured the system, so there is probably more than one possible answer to your question.
In general, TYPO3 sites are typically configured using TypoScript (read more about what TypoScript is). The TypoScript configuration can be stored in database records, in an extension (typically a SitePackage), or in the file system.
You can manipulate the output, including the HTML <head> by changing the configuration of the PAGE object (see reference documentation).
You might also check if the SEO extension meets your requirement.
Once again, please understand that further details about the individual setup of your TYPO3 site are required to guide you through the steps on how to adjust the frontend output including the header.

Actually I cannot determine how the individual setup is made. I tried editing the template from the backend Template option, selecting the very first template and CHanging themode to Typoscript. I can see there's a meta section bu no idea how to add the gtm tracking code there.
I can see fluid style as extension so that is an option. And when I try editing the header template code, there's no other option than hello world. How is this flexible?
